# Execute R Script on AWS via API

Tags: r, api, amazon-web-services

I have an R package that I would like to host through Amazon Web Services that will be accessible via an API.  The script should take a couple of input values and return the R output in json format.  Also, the API should be able to handle multiple requests simultaneously.

So for example, call http://sampleapi.com/?location=USA?state=Florida.  That would then run the R package and return the output data to the calling application.

Has anyone done this before or know of resources you can point me to that would explain how to do so?  Thanks!

Comment: https://www.opencpu.org/ is one option that's relatively complex. or  https://github.com/trestletech/plumber that simply exposes functions via api routes

Comment: Jupyter notebooks can be used as [RESTful microservices](http://blog.ibmjstart.net/2016/01/28/jupyter-notebooks-as-restful-microservices/). You should read up on [securing](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/notebook/security.html) Jupyter/IPython, including what others have done in [multiuser environments](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Notebook-kernels-LXC-td4993316.html).

Comment: https://rforge.net/FastRWeb/ This package makes it pretty easy to do this, but you have to be proficient at launching an AWS instance and configuring it in order to be successful with any of these package suggestions.

Comment: @sckott Thanks, I had checked out plumber before, that looks like it will be useful.  My main concern though is how to make the package available online.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I assume you're running a server on aws with R installed, i haven't tested, but I imagine you can expose the API that plumber exposes like <IP address:port> - no idea about security concerns though

Comment: I don't have a server set up yet.  I'm trying to find out if I need to set up an EC2 server and that will allow multiple hits to the url at the same time or if I need to run something different.

Comment: There's few options available that don't require you to setup your own server. https://deployr.revolutionanalytics.com/ may work, never used it though.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the suggestions.  I decided to use Ruby for the API with the `rinruby` and `rails-api` gems and will host that through AWS Elastic Beanstalk.  See this question for how I am setting it up - [Ruby API - Accept parameters and execute script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36584789/ruby-api-accept-parameters-and-execute-script)

Comment: Using the microframework Flask to convert existing Python code into APIs is also a  possibility; hosting Flask on AWS Elasticbeanstalk comes out of the box.