# Ruby API - Accept parameters and execute script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rails-api

I have created a rails project that has some code that I would like to execute as an API.  I am using the rails-api gem.

The file is located in app/controllers/api/stats.rb.

I would like to be able to execute that script and return json output by visiting a link such as this - http://sampleapi.com/stats/?location=USA?state=Florida.

How should I configure my project so that when I visit that link it runs my code?

Comment: I think for the URL you meant `http://sampleapi.com/stats/?location=USA&state=Florida`. URL query string is only allowed a single "?" which separates the query string from the path.

Comment: Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the file should be called `stats_controller.rb` `app/controllers/api/stats_controller.rb`

you can create an `index` method where you can add your code

```
  class API::StatsController < ApplicationController  
    def index
       #your code here
       render json: your_result
    end    
  end
```

in the file `config/routes.rb` you should add

```
get 'stats' => 'api/stats#index', as: 'stats'
```

To access the params in the url you can do it in your index method with `params[:location]` ,`params[:state]`

Comment: I keep getting this error and I'm not sure how to get around it.  

`Unable to autoload constant API::StatsController, expected /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/controllers/api/stats_controller.rb to define it`

Comment: your controller name should be `Api::StatsController`

Comment: Ok thank you very much! That worked but you have to have API in all caps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would think of this:

in app/controllers/api/stats_controller.rb

```
module Api
  class StatsController
    def index
      # your code implementation
      # you can also fetch/filter your query strings here params[:location] or params[:state]
      render json: result # dependent on if you have a view
    end
  end
end
```

in config/routes.rb

```
# the path option changes the path from `/api` to `/` so in this case instead of /api/stats you get /stats
namespace :api, path: '/', defaults: { format: :json } do
  resources :stats, only: [:index] # or other actions that should be allowed here
end
```

Let me know if this works